# While loop which SHOULD return a new random integer after every run

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, random, while-loop

I am currently working on a board game. I am having a bit of trouble when it comes to coding the dice. For some reason, the while loop keeps returning the same random integer after every run instead of a new one.

this is how far I have got:

```
def dice():



    turtle.addshape("bull.gif")

    player1 = turtle.Turtle()
    player1.shape("bull.gif")
    player1.penup()
    player1.goto(-240, -260)



    turtle.addshape("cow.gif")

    player2 = turtle.Turtle()
    player2.shape("cow.gif")

    player2.penup()
    player2.goto(-240, -220)



    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)

   


    p1_list = ([-240, -260], [-120, -260], [0, -260], [120, -260], [240, -260], [240, -140], [120, -140], [0, -140], [-120, -140], [-240, -140], [-240, -20], [-120, -20], [0, -20], [120, -20], [240, -20], [240, 100], [120, 100], [0, 100], [-120, 100], [-240, 100], [-240, 220], [-120, 220], [0, 220], [120, 220], [240, 220])

    p2_list = ([-240, -220], [-120, -220], [0, -220], [120, -220], [240, -220], [240, -100], [120, -100], [0, -100], [-120, -100], [-240, -100], [-240, 20], [-120, 20], [0, 20], [120, 20], [240, 20],[ 240, 140], [120, 140], [0, 140], [-120, 140], [-240, 140], [-240, 260], [-120, 260], [0, 260], [120, 260], [240, 260])

    

    dieValue = dice1
    P1_pos = player1.goto(p1_list[0])
    pos = 0

    w = True

    while w == True:

        player1_dice = input("\nBULL (P1): Please press 'ENTER' to roll the dice ")
        
if player1_dice == "":
            print("BULL (P1) rolled a", dice1)

        elif player1_dice != "":
            print("BULL (P1): Please make sure to press 'ENTER' ")

        for pos in range(dieValue) :
            pos += 1
            P1_pos =  player1.goto(p1_list[pos])

        pos = pos


dice()
```

Comment: `dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)` This only gets called once, before the loop. Move it to inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

this whole part is unnecessary in this case since it accomplishes nothing. no matter what will be inputed they always have to press enter so even if they input something code will move on:

```
        if player1_dice == "":
            print("BULL (P1) rolled a", dice1)

        elif player1_dice != "":
            print("BULL (P1): Please make sure to press 'ENTER' ")
```

You are completely fine with just this:

```
        print("BULL (P1) rolled a", dice1)
```

Anyhow about the while loop it should be fine just like this:

```
import random

while True:
    input("\nBULL (P1): Please press 'ENTER' to roll the dice ")

    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)

    print("BULL (P1) rolled a", dice1)
```

just make sure that You import random at the beginning of the file

so from this point You should be fine, You can now use the `dice1` variable however there has to be a way to exit the loop otherwise the code will be stuck in there forever. so maybe use some break statement or thread the function and at the end return the value (then tho there is no point of even having a loop, you can just call the function in a while loop) but do as You wish

Comment: thanks, the other problem I am facing is that the latest position of the P1 won't be store it will always return to the vale inside pos which is 0. I would like the incrementation inside the for loop to be saved so that P1 will start from its previous position and not again from 0. I was wondering whether I need to create a new additional variable or not and if so how?

Comment: @Kaja when will it return? when You terminate the program and run it again?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get a different value for each run. I have placed the dice1 variable inside the loop.

but I need to find a way to store the latest pos value. so that the character won't start again from the default position instead it should start from the previous position.